# Workaround for Array.prototype.every() to match elements in array && not in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```js
var groupArray = [
    ['10', 'group one result', 'more result from group1'],
    ['10 20 30', 'group two result', 'another result from group two'],
    ['10 20 40', 'group three result']
];

function compare(entryArr, stringArr) {
    for (var i in entryArr) {
        str = stringArr.split(' '); //to array
        ent = entryArr[i][0].split(' ');  //first items of each group to array

        if (str.every(s => ent.includes(s)))  // compare 
    return entryArr[i].slice(1);
    }
}
//find match from possible strings
console.log(compare(groupArray, '10')) // true
console.log(compare(groupArray, '10 20')) // true
console.log(compare(groupArray, '10 20 60')) // undefined. the result should come from group two
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Above is the structure of my project.

I need to return the most relevant result when comparing string and entry arrays.

`Array.prototype.every()` Is the closest I've got in achieving my goal after countless hours trial and error of trying...

The problem is shown in output #3. I understand `Array.prototype.every()` will return false if the element to find is not present in the array but there must be a workaround.

If I remove non similar elements on both arrays, I thought it would solve the problem.

```
xyz = str.filter(x => ent.includes(x)) //output: ['10','20'] for sample #3
```

I try to use xyz as the new array for strings but then the element in entry array will still be present, thus will return false.

I can get the difference on both arrays...

```
entArr = str.filter(x => !ent.includes(x)) // entry array difference

strArr = ent.filter(x => !str.includes(x)) // string array difference
```

...but then I'm stuck in trying to find the suitable condition to apply.

Hope I explained it well and thanks for your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a filter to find all items that contain each string, keeping track of the count and the position of those that do to find the first one that has the most matches.

Something like:

```js
var groupArray = [
    ['10', 'group one result'],
    ['10 20 30', 'group two result'],
    ['10 20 40', 'group three result']
];

function compare(entryArr, stringArr) {
  let pos = 0;
  let matches = 0;
    for (var i in entryArr) {
      str = stringArr.split(' ');
      ent = entryArr[i][0].split(' ');
      let f = str.filter(s => ent.includes(s));
      if (f)
        if (f.length > matches) {
          pos = i;
          matches = f.length;
        }
    }
    if (matches > 0) {
      return entryArr[pos].slice(1);
    } else {
      return [];
    }
}
//find match from possible strings
console.log(compare(groupArray, '10')) // returns first entry that matches one value - group one result
console.log(compare(groupArray, '10 20')) // returns first entry that matches both values - group two result
console.log(compare(groupArray, '10 20 60')) // returns first entry with 2 matches - group two result
console.log(compare(groupArray, '50 60 80')) // no matches, returns empty array
```

** UPDATE: to return multiple group names where matches have been found, ordered by match count then by group numbers **

```js
var groupArray = [
    ['10', 'group one result', 'more one result'],
    ['10 20 40', 'group three result'],
    ['10 20 30', 'group two result'],
    ['10 20 30 40', 'group four result'],
    ['20 60', 'group five result']
];

function compare(entryArr, stringArr) {
  // Array to hold ALL matches found
  let matched = [];
  // Loop through the entryArry array
  for (let i = 0; i < entryArr.length; i++) {
    // split search string into separate values
    str = stringArr.split(' ');
    // split the main array into separate values
    ent = entryArr[i][0].split(' ');
    // find any main array items that contain the search string values
    let f = str.filter(s => ent.includes(s));
    // If found...
    if (f.length > 0) {
      //... push into the matched array
      matched.push([f.length, ...entryArr[i]]);
    }
  }
  // If we have more than one match found, sort the matched array
  // First by match count descending, then by the main array values, ascending
  if (matched.length > 1) {
    matched.sort(function(a, b){
      if (a[0] == b[0]) {
        return a[1] > b[1];
      } else {
        return a[0] < b[0];
      }
    })
    // Now remove the unnecessary parts of each match
    // We only want the group name, not the match count or the group's numbers string
    for (let i = 0; i < matched.length; i++) {
      matched[i] = matched[i].slice(2);
    }
  }
  // return the result
  return matched;
}

//find match from possible strings
console.log(compare(groupArray, '10'));
console.log(compare(groupArray, '10 20'));
console.log(compare(groupArray, '10 20 60'));
console.log(compare(groupArray, '20 30 40'));
```

Comment: Thanks sir! I'm testing it in my project and it's flawless so far :)

Comment: np.  Just out of curiosity though, is there a reason for just wanting to get the first array with the most matches?  All the ones I've done and seen like this would have wanted to get both the "two" and "three" results.

Comment: I actually just wanted to display the array with the most relevant match.. then return random item from the group where it found the match. And you solved my problem :) thanks again!

Comment: OK, np.  I've actually just updated the code, though.  The "splice(1)" function actually removes part of an array, so it is gone for good.  I've changed that part to create an simple array using just the contents of it instead - `[entryArr[pos][1]]`

Comment: nope, ur first code is fine. we use slice(1) so it wont return the first items on each group. We only need that part to store keywords.

Comment: np - I've rolled back my change to show the slice() version again.

Comment: Hi sir, I've been trying to set another condition to SHOW ALL possible results in sorted order,  but still no success, i hope u can still help if it's not too much to ask...

Comment: like when we call this compare(groupArray, '30 40') it will show group 2 and group 3, but not group 1.

Comment: That is relatively easy to achieve.  What would be the sort order though?  If you sort by the result name, yours would be "one", "three", "two" as it would be alphabetical.  You could sort by the first part - the "10", "10 20 30", "10 20 40" bits but they would have to be included in the output to make sense of the results order as, presumably, the numbers could be anything?.  Or, they could be sorted by the number of matches - eg, if 3 numbers match, put those first, followed by the 2's then the 1's?

Comment: the most matched result will be on top. im trying my best to learn and still a long way to go..

Comment: OK - do you still only want to see "group one result", "group two result" etc etc, or do you need to see the number of matches and, perhaps, the values stored for "group one result" etc?

Comment: yup, all groups with matching elements will be shown but it will be just sorted by the number of matched elements.

Comment: So, just the names for the groups, sorted by most matches first?

Comment: for example, on the answer you provided, if we call compare(groupArray, '20 40'), group two and three will be shown but grp 3 will be on top coz it has the most matched elements. grp 1 wont be shown coz no matched elements.

Comment: OK - have a look at the second snippet in my Answer above.

Comment: yup the sorting is perfect :) we just have to make the result to be ["group one result"],["group three result"] etc..

Comment: also i tried to add more items inside the group but it only showed 'group one result', not   'more one result' >>>  ['10', 'group one result', 'more one result']

Comment: but probably I can solve that part, but it wud be nice to see the solution coming from a pro :)

Comment: OK - try the second snippet now

Comment: From matched[i][2] to matched[i] then I solved the problem. Thanks so much sir for your help, surely I will learn a lot from here!

Comment: yup perfect. 

Comment: np - you can play around with that line to include the match count, group number string and the group name(s)

Comment: hi sir, answer above is returning least matched to most matched results.  I tried my best to fix it and it was a success, pls check if I did it right then u can update your last answer, thanks!  https://jsbin.com/jebuvuz/2/edit?js,console

Comment: As long as the sort function is `return b[0] - a[0];`, then it will sort the highest matchcount values first.  My example also sorts by group, but you can ignore that bit.  In the example you have, "group four result" should appear first as it contains two matches and all of the others only contain one.